# Как изменить дату рождения в Adobe ID для испольнония фунций бета-версии Photoshop?

Tags: авторизация, photoshop, adobe

[image: скриншот]

Купил фотошоп для того, чтобы опробовать генеративную заливку, а там нельзя использовать функцию из-за того, что «вам нет 18 лет» (на самом деле мне 19 лет).

Как изменить дату рождения в Adobe ID?

Answer (score 0):

Два варианта, в зависимости от того, регистрировались ли вы на свой почтовый ящик или с использованием экаунта социальной сети. Проверенная методика смены даты рождения такова (привожу оба варианта):

1. (на свой почтовый ящик) Заходите и в Creative Cloud, и в бета-версию Фотошопа. Затем - в [Behance](https://www.behance.net/) со своим AdobeID и вводите дату рождения.
2. (с использованием соц. сети) Сделать то же самое, предварительно проверив, стоит ли правильная дата рождения в профиле соц. сети, и она доступна для считывания сторонними сервисами.

Всё. Теперь нужно перезапустить бета-версию Фотошопа.